# Path parsing for ReST API in Spray

Tags: scala, spray, spray-dsl

I have following code in Spray to parse the REST service called by user:

```
val route = {
  pathPrefix("v0") {
    pathPrefix("pets") {
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        pathEnd {
          get {
            complete("/v0/pets")
          }
        } ~
        get {
          complete("/v0/pets/")
        }
      } ~
      parameters('id ?) {
        id =>
          get {
            complete("/v0/pets?id=" + id)
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that it is not behaving as expected.
I am expecting following behaviour from the code:

```
http://127.0.0.1/v0/pets => /v0/pets
http://127.0.0.1/v0/pets/ => /v0/pets/
http://127.0.0.1/v0/pets?id=1234 = > /v0/pets?id=Some(1234)
```

But, I am getting following results for the queries:

```
http://127.0.0.1/v0/pets => /v0/pets
http://127.0.0.1/v0/pets/ => /v0/pets
http://127.0.0.1/v0/pets?id=1234 => /v0/pets
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the issue here is that since `id` is declared as `optional` your `parameter` route handles both the presence and the **absence** of it (and that is handling `v0/pets`).

One way of doing it (and I also assume you only want to handle `get` requests).

You basically just declare `id` **not optional** on your `parameter` route:

```
val route = get {
  pathPrefix("v0") {
    pathPrefix("pets") {
      pathEnd {
        parameter('id) { id =>
          complete("/v0/pets?id=" + id)
        } ~ complete("/v0/pets")
      } ~
      pathSingleSlash {
        complete("/v0/pets/")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another way basically just exploits the fact that `id` is an optional parameter, so you just pattern match on the `Option`:

```
val route = {
  pathPrefix("v0") {
    pathPrefix("pets") {
      pathEnd {
        get {
          parameters('id ?) { id =>
            id match {
              case Some(id) => complete("/v0/pets?id=" + id)
              case None => complete("/v0/pets")
            }
          }
        }
      } ~
      pathSingleSlash {
        get {
          complete("/v0/pets/")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pathPrefix("v0") {
  pathPrefix("pets") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      get {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

matches http://127.0.0.1/v0/pets?id=1234.

This is why

```
GET /v0/pets?id=1234
 ^   ^   ^  ^
 |___|___|__|____ get  
     |   |  |
     |   |  |
     |   |  |__ pathEndOrSlash
     |   |  
     |   |__ pathPrefix("pets")
     |
     |__ pathPrefix("v0")
```

You need to intercept the `parameter` before. Try

```
val route = {
  pathPrefix("v0") {
    pathPrefix("pets") {
      parameters('id ?) {
        id =>
          get {
            complete("/v0/pets?id=" + id)
          }
      } ~
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        pathEnd {
          get {
            complete("/v0/pets")
          }
        } ~
        get {
          complete("/v0/pets/")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @gabriele-petronella for your reply. But with your suggested solution, the last two paths are never executed. Both of them simply get executed by the first path only and print output as /v0/pets/?id=None

Comment: oh yes, my bad, the optionality of `id` makes it enter the first path anyway. mfirry's solution is the way to go.